# Lookup an ejb on same server and cell

Tags: ejb, websphere, jndi

I have an ejb application  Xdate and a web application Y deployed on websphere server/cell and the web app uses client jar of Xdate ejb to lookup. Can I use name space binding of "ejb type" to lookup this ejb through my web app? Note that ejb app and web app are two different apps on same server. How can I lookup an ejb deployed on the same server using name space binding

I am using below string for lookup.
"java:comp/env/ejbs/XdateRemote"

Entry in web.xml

Comment: What version of java EE and Websphere are you using?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have an enterprise application called `X`, which contains an EJB module. Plus, you have an enterprise application called `Y`, which contains a web module. You'd like the web module in `Y` to be able to refer to EJB's contained within `X`.

If that is correct, then you don't necessarily need an EJB namespace binding for this to work. If the two applications are running on the same server (and you mentioned that that is the case), then both access the same JNDI tree.

The EJB namespace binding is required when the client and the EJB are running on separate targets within the same cell.